# How to get proper email uniqueness in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Rspec throws errors:

```
 1) Client uniqueness validates uniqueness of email
     Failure/Error: expect(subject).to validate_uniqueness_of :email

       Client did not properly validate that :email is case-sensitively unique.
         After taking the given Client, whose :email is
         ‹"jaleel_wehner@okonwiegand.name"›, and saving it as the existing
         record, then making a new Client and setting its :email to a different
         value, ‹"JALEEL_WEHNER@OKONWIEGAND.NAME"›, the matcher expected the
         new Client to be valid, but it was invalid instead, producing these
         validation errors:

         * pesel: ["This pesel is already in database"]
         * email: ["This email is already in database"]
```

In model I have implemented uniqueness and case-sensitive: false for email.

```
  validates :email, presence: true,
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
```

I also have implemented method, that all email downcase before validation.

```
  def downcase_email
    self.email = email.downcase if email.present?
  end
before_validation :downcase_email
```

Why matcher expected that new Client will be valid? It should be invalid.

```
subject { FactoryGirl.build(:client) }
it 'validates uniqueness of email' do
  expect(subject).to validate_uniqueness_of :email
end
```

Client has a valid factory. I tried find good solution, but I haven't found anything that would solve my problem.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :client do
    pesel { Faker::Number.number(11) }
    first_name { Faker::Name.first_name }
    last_name { Faker::Name.last_name }
    date_of_birth { Faker::Time.between('1970-01-01', '2000-12-31') }
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
    password { Faker::Internet.password }
    type 'Client'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FactoryGirl has the following example for your issue within it's documentation

```
sequence :email do |n|
    "person#{n}@example.com"
  end

factory :invite do
  invitee { generate(:email) }
end
```

Edit after your updates:

The issue is the matcher `validate_uniqueness_of`. You have to adjust `case_sensitive` for the matcher too. So it should be `validate_uniqueness_of(:email).case_insensitive`

Comment: I use faker to generate data.

Comment: See my update, it's the matcher which produces the error.

Comment: Thank you slowjack2k!! Now it's great. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if your factory has curved brackets wrapping the email attribute like such:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :client do
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
  end
end
```

Comment: show my updated post how looks like my client factory. I wrote that client has valid factory.

Comment: A factory without the curved brackets still valid, but does not guarantee the uniqueness of the value generated, The factory wasn't on the first post so I presumed that could be the problem. Apologies.